# php: load input from another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm working on a page with several user inputs and a 'save' button within a form.

However, the values of one input are **sections(like §1.a) )** generated depending on checkboxes the user selects from a list in another (popup)window, in this case there is **no inputarea** in the form but an "add"-button(or link)

```
<form action="save.php" method="post">
  <div>several inputs<input></div>
  <div>and textareas<...></div>

  <div>sections:<a href="select.php">select sections</div>

<input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

How do I manage to display the select window, and when the user selected some check boxes return to the form, insert the sections without losing the input from before and then being able to save all these values?

edit:Using ajax is permitted by project-constraints

Comment: use [ajax](http://learn.jquery.com/events/)

Comment: U can use $_SESSION First store the inputed data in session then use it from it as long you want. then unset the session when your task will done..